# Why is hidden field not recognised after POST

Tags: php

This should be straight forward but I cannot get it to work with POST.
I have a hidden field called run_api. When submitting the form it redirects to itself running a script that checks the value of run_api field, running an API dependant on the value.
For some reason if I use POST it isn't recognised while having type='hidden' and I cannot figure out why. If I use GET it seems to work. Can someone advise as to why?
Thanks

I have an index page with the form on it with the script being clled at the top of the page. The script file determines the value of the run_api field then runs a script. it should recoginise run_api equalling 1 and then run script 1 in the iff else statement. but it dosen't and  I get undefined array key.

FORM

```html
<form name= "execute_api" action="index.php" method="POST" target="_self" enctype="text/plain" >
<input  type="hidden" name="which_api" value="api_01">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-gradient dark btn-block">
RUN API CALL
</button>
</form>
```

SCRIPT

```php
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {

    $update_msg = "NO - API has not been executed" ;
    $run_this = "empty"  ;
}
elseif($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $update_msg = "YES - API has been executed" ;
    $run_this = $_POST['which_api']  ;
}
?>
```

RESULT

> Warning: Undefined array key "which_api" in (index_scripts) on line 5

Comment: Is that the real code? I ask because the error says **line 5** and you dont reference `which_api` until **line 8** in the example code

Comment: Yes. I've taken the script out of the page. the form is on index.php, when posted it reloads and the index_script.php is run (it is included at the top of the page. which_api is the hidden field that is posted with the form

Answer (score 3):

`enctype="text/plain"` is an encoding that is:

- not supported by PHP
- not reliably machine readable (which is a good part of the reason it isn't supported by PHP)
- intended only for debugging (but not as good as a parser for a decent encoding (like the one built into the Network tab of a browser's developer tools) for that)

---

Use an encoding that PHP supports instead. The default (Form URL Encoding) is fine. Remove the `enctype` attribute.